# Json reference conflict in SignalR project

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, signalr

Yesterday I began developing a SignalR application - I created 2 different projects (server and client), and everything worked smoothly.

Today, I opened it again - and now it is causing problems.

This is my client code:

```
signalrHub.client.updateVehicle = function (dbVehicle) {
    $.each(Vehicles, function() {
        var vehicle = this;
        if (vehicle.id == dbVehicle.id && vehicle.dataset == dbVehicle.dataset) {
            vehicle.move(dbVehicle.latitude, dbVehicle.longitude);
        }
    });
};
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:52522/signalr";
signalrHub = $.connection.routeHub;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
    signalrHub.server.joinDataset("JR");
    signalrHub.server.getVehicles("JR").done(function (response) {
        $.each(response.vehicles, function() {
            Vehicles.push(new Vehicle(this));
        });
        $.each(Vehicles, function() {
            this.addToMap();
        });
    }).fail(function(error) {
        alert(error);
    });
});
```

The fail handler gets called, with the following error:
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've tried updating Newtonsoft.Json to 6.0 - but then I got a compiling error looking for version 4.5.

This is the GetVehicles on the server side:

```
public async Task<Vehicles> GetVehicles(string dataset)
{
    var vehicles = await Vehicles.GetData(dataset, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
    Clients.Caller.updateVehicle(vehicles.Data.First());
    return vehicles;
}
```

and this is the line where it fails:

```
Clients.Caller.updateVehicle(vehicles.Data.First());
```

If I remove that - the method will execute all the way to the end, and the client times out and never receives the Vehicles object.

Answer (score 9):

Another edge case, if you're using `signalr.exe ghp ...` command to manually generate the javascript files (i.e. for unit testing, etc.), you can get around the issue with a similar work around as the `web.config` answer above.

Just create a regular app.config file (i.e. `signalr.exe.config`) in the same place as `signalr.exe` and place the following contents in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly (after Google API required 7.0.1 of Newtonsoft). Thank you.

Comment: A new version of Newtonsoft.Json is out and I needed to bump the binding redirect to use "8.0.0.0".

Answer (score 3):

Add an `app.config` with assembly redirect, i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <!-- Redirect SignalR JSON -->
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I had am using signalr (compiled with Newtonsoft.Json 4.5) to generate hub proxy (ghp parm) from my dll that uses Newtonsoft.Json 6.0. I had to create a signalr.exe.config with larsm's contents to avoid signalr ghp throwing the cannot load exception.

Comment: That was not the solution but helped me a lot. In fact, I directly modified the binding redirect in the webconfig file

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message in my project.  My setup looked like this:

- Web (an ASP.NET MVC 5 project for views and web content - **dependencies**:

  - Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.6 (from MVC project template)
  - WebPresentationModel (C# class library for controllers and viewmodels) - **dependencies**:

    - Newtonsoft.Json (added 6.0.1 via NuGet)

So after I updated my 'Web' project via NuGet to Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1 the error went away.  Perhaps you had a similar issue with different projects referencing different versions of Newtonsoft?  Looks like the .NET 4.5 thing is really your issue now.  Do you have .NET Framework 4.5 (or 4.5.1) set as your Target framework in Project Properties?

Comment: I don't have a .NET problem. By 4.5 I meant Newtonsoft.Json v 4.5

Comment: Ah, OK.  I would try Uninstall-Package Newtonsoft.Json, clean project and try Install-Package again.  If you continue to get any assembly loading errors I would try and troubleshoot with [fusion log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx).  Do you have any other projects or dependencies in your projects that may depend on Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: Thank you Tom! You lead me in the right direction as to checking if any other of my projects were using Newtonsoft.Json. I did have another project in the solution where I had added Json from NuGet manager, and it took the newest version. This caused the conflicts in the signalR project that requires 4.5. I removed the dependency to 6.0 and added a reference to the same dll as the signalR project uses, and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

No doubt this will only be a temporary edge case, but I had this exact same problem (System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json') with the Windows 10 preview - Visual Studio 2015 RC combination... it turned out that I was using a pre-release version of Newtonsoft Json (v7.0.1 beta) in my solution.

To fix this, I downgraded through NuGet to Newtonsoft Json v6.0.8 and from then ghp worked fine.